# How do I reference a second sheet column across a row of numbers in sheet 1

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to look-up a value in sheet 2 from a number on a row in sheet one: it looks like this:

Sheet 1:

```
Row4 Number of units    0   5   25  10  15
```

And sheet 2:

```
column a column b

1   
2   
3   
4   
5        10.00%
6        11.00%
7        12.00%
8        13.00%
9        14.00%
```

Comment: You want to search for `5` in sheet 2?

Answer (score 1):

In Sheet 1, do a VLOOKUP on Sheet2:

```
=VLOOKUP(A4,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$9,2)
```

where A4 is the value you're looking up in the table $A$1:$B$9 on Sheet2, and return the value in column 2 of the row you find the value of A4 in.

Do this for every value in Sheet 1.